# Why is HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode marked as "do not use"?

Tags: asp.net, .net, urlencode, url-encoding

Why does the documentation of .NET for [HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for .NET 4.5 state

> Do not use; intended only for browser compatibility. Use UrlEncode.

UrlEncode does not do the same, it encodes a string for the parameter part of a URL, not for the path part. Is there a better way to encode a string for the path part and why shouldn't I use this function, which is in the framework since 1.1 and works?

Comment: "can be used to encode the entire URL, including query-string values."

But UrlEncode doesn't work for relative URLs, at least if the do not have parameters. it encodes spaces as + and also encodes the slashes in the path.

Comment: I'm guessing .Net detects a browser which has limited/no support for unicode characters in the path and encodes them to avoid problems, but I'd love to know for sure...

Answer (score 2):

based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx), they recommend to use UrlEncode to grantee that it is working for all platforms and browsers

> You can encode a URL using with the UrlEncode method or the UrlPathEncode method. However, the methods return different results. The UrlEncode method converts each space character to a plus character (+). The UrlPathEncode method converts each space character into the string "%20", which represents a space in hexadecimal notation. Use the UrlPathEncode method when you encode the path portion of a URL in order to guarantee a consistent decoded URL, regardless of which platform or browser performs the decoding.

Also UrlEncode is using UTF-8 encoding so if you are sending query string in different language like Arabic you should use UrlEncode

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Uri.EscapeUriString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapeuristring) if you want encode a path of a URL. [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode) is for query parameters and encode also slashes which is wrong for a path.